# Geometric interpretation of ring quotients

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring (let it be notherian if it helps). You have the canonical quotient map $$R \to R / I$$ for some ideal $I$, where elements of $R$ are sent to their corresponding ideals etc.

If we go to Geometry land we have this (canonical?) map:
$$\operatorname{Spec}R/I\to\operatorname{Spec}R$$
If we let $R$ be some algebraically closed field's polynomial ring in two variables $k[x,y]$ then this is saying there is always a map of an affine variety into the affine plane. This is great but how am I supposed to think about $I$? What geometric object does $I$ correspond to? Can I take ring quotients without ever leaving Geometry land?

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! The generators of $I$ are the equations defining the affine variety, and $\sqrt I$ is the  ideal which vanish on the variety, what else do you want to say?

Comment: @Bernard I mean if Affine schemes and commutative rings are equivalent then shouldn't constructions in one correspond to constructions in the other?

Answer (score 1):

In Geometry Land $I$ corresponds to a closed subscheme $V(I)\subset \mathbb A^2_k$.
The most interesting case is when $I=\langle P(x,y)\rangle$, the principal ideal generated by a non-constant polynomial $P(x,y)$.
The subscheme $V(I)$ is then a curve.
  Beware however that this curve might have several irreducible components, and morover these components may have multiplicities.
But all in all  $V(I)$ is not so far from what pioneers, like Descartes, of our beloved Algebraic Geometry understood under the word "curve".
For example if $P(x,y)=(x^2+y^2-1)x^2$ the curve consists of the union of a circle and a double line.
Grothendieck's remarkable insight in the 1950's was that one could similarly view geometrically any ideal in a completely arbitrary ring $A$ having nothing to do with polynomials.
Any such ring has a Geometry Land  $=\operatorname {Spec}(A)\;$ covered by an intricate web of subschemes $V(I)=\operatorname {Spec}(A/I)$.